# ESP8266 NodeMCU MicroPython garbage in serial, cannot erase_flash or upload files

Tags: esp8266, nodemcu, micropython, mcu

Looks like I broke my NodeMCU Lolin esp8266 module, please confirm)

Firstly everything worked fine, but then...

1. I uploaded a bit strange `boot.py` to play with UART0

```
#boot.py
import uos, machine
import gc
gc.collect()

import esp
import time

esp.osdebug(None)
uart = machine.UART(0, 115200)

def uart_test():
    print('before disabling REPL on UART')
    uos.dupterm(None, 1) # disable REPL on UART(0)
    print('after detaching REPL')
    time.sleep(5)
    uart.write('123')
    r=uart.read()
    # reattach REPL
    uos.dupterm(uart, 1)
    print('after attaching REPL')
    print('r: ')
    print(r)
```

2. Then I uploaded `main.py` with blink in infinity loop with time.sleep() to check state while I mount module in box.

```
#main.py
import time
from machine import Pin, Signal

led = Signal(2, mode=Pin.OUT, invert=True)
while True:
    led.on()
    time.sleep(1)
    led.off()
    time.sleep(1)
```

3. Then, when I was mounting module in box I accidentally tore one element from PCB, but then solder it back. I don't know what is this element and what purpose of it. I marked this element on image
   [IMG: broken element](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aE9W7.png)

And after all of that I cannot connect to module by serial port, I see only garbage in screen, tried different baud rates.
[IMG: screen is empty and doesen't react to keys or Ctrl+C](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wVOT0.png)

After resetting board only garbage in screen [IMG: garbage after reset](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N9uIC.png)

Also I cannot erase flash using `esptool`.

MCU is working because when it powered led is blinking as it programmed in `main.py`

I tried to enable bootloader mode by connecting `GPIO0` with `GND`, blink is not working in this mode, but `esptool.py` also doesn't work in this mode.
esptool log

```
python3 -m esptool --port /dev/cu.usbserial-142240 --baud 9600 erase_flash
esptool.py v3.1
Serial port /dev/cu.usbserial-142240
Connecting........_____....._____....._____....._____....._____....._____....._____

A fatal error occurred: Failed to connect to Espressif device: Timed out waiting for packet header
```

esptool log with --trace arg

```
python3 -m esptool --port /dev/cu.usbserial-142240 --baud 115200 --trace erase_flash
esptool.py v3.1
Serial port /dev/cu.usbserial-142240
Connecting...TRACE +0.000 command op=0x08 data len=36 wait_response=1 timeout=0.100 data=
    0707122055555555 5555555555555555 | ... UUUUUUUUUUUU
    5555555555555555 5555555555555555 | UUUUUUUUUUUUUUUU
    55555555                          | UUUU
TRACE +0.000 Write 46 bytes: 
    c000082400000000 0007071220555555 | ...$........ UUU
    5555555555555555 5555555555555555 | UUUUUUUUUUUUUUUU
    5555555555555555 5555555555c0     | UUUUUUUUUUUUU.
TRACE +0.023 Read 1 bytes: e2
TRACE +0.000 Read invalid data: e2
TRACE +0.000 Remaining data in serial buffer: 
    6efe6ee43cfe2792 07eceeee708ef21c | n.n.<.'.....p...
    1e0e1c906e6c6c1c 9227c71eeee76c   | ....nll..'....l
.TRACE +0.056 command op=0x08 data len=36 wait_response=1 timeout=0.100 data=
    0707122055555555 5555555555555555 | ... UUUUUUUUUUUU
    5555555555555555 5555555555555555 | UUUUUUUUUUUUUUUU
    55555555                          | UUUU
TRACE +0.000 Write 46 bytes: 
    c000082400000000 0007071220555555 | ...$........ UUU
    5555555555555555 5555555555555555 | UUUUUUUUUUUUUUUU
    5555555555555555 5555555555c0     | UUUUUUUUUUUUU.
TRACE +0.002 Read 1 bytes: ee
TRACE +0.000 Read invalid data: ee
TRACE +0.000 Remaining data in serial buffer: 
    240eec6e9c9c8c9c e70e026c6ce4ee9c | $..n.......ll...
    6e6e00f26c62e4ee 70e26ee2ec626c   | nn..lb..p.n..bl
...
# and a lot of similar messages
```

What is with my nodemcu module is it died or not? What can I try to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Conclusion:

Today I received USB to UART converter, connected it to TX and RX of my ESP8266 board and everything works well. So the problem is with onboard CH340 converter.

Answer (score 1):

It's more likely that you are experiencing hardware related issues than software related issues as you imply yourself.

Re-solder the part that broke off and try again. You probably broke of a resistor/capacitor that is used for noise filtering the output (I am not a hardware guy) or something that is vital to regulating the voltage required for the board to operate.

EDIT

As indicated by: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/hallard/NodeMCU-Gateway/master/pictures/NodeMCU-Lora-Gateway-top.png it seems, albeit that board is of a different design, that you broke off a capacitor or diode. Either resolder or get yourself a new one (100nf) or a diode (1N4148)

Comment: I tried it several times, there is no effect. I think thai I burned some elements in CH304 serial to usb converter circuit. And it's cause why it's not working. I have external usb to uart converter, maybe I'll try to connect through it, or buy new one nodemcu.

Anyway, thanks for advise!

Comment: I figured out that it's diode on the PCB board, I soldered it out and similar neighbour diode. Checked it by multimeter in diode test mode and both works proper. Then soldered it back, but it doesn't helped.